# loginForm, selfRegister, selfStartUrl in Lightning Components must be packaged

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, community-builder, community-template

I have created a managed package which also includes Custom Community template(from Napili template). When I submitted this package for Security review I got a response as below:

> loginForm, selfRegister, selfStartUrl in Lightning Components must be packaged

Why are these components required to be packaged, as I am not using Custom Login form, nor the Self Register feature?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this might be necessary is your subscriber may customise login ,registration screens and may want to extend with lightning components .

So you should include these as a part of managed package so that they can extend it .